# Is there anyway to speed up opening a save with Google Play Games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm using the official Google Play Games plugin for Unity. I'm using `OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution`to open a particular save. The problem is that it's incredibly slow. On average it takes 400 to 500 ms to complete and in some cases it can take up to 8 seconds. I'm timing the process using this code

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(filename, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
            ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseOriginal, (status, data) =>
            {
                sw.Stop();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"[SW] Open {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

The save files are not particularly huge, less than 40 KB. Additionally I would expect on-device caching to prevent such long loading times. Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Seems you're not alone: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1111024/seeing-slow-performance-on-play-games-plugin-for-u.html